# How to achieve "responsiveness" of this template?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-applications, responsive-design

I'm looking at this template:

http://www.meanthemes.com/theme/daily/photo/

I'll have tiles on my site similar to this, however I'm not sure how to get started with moving the tiles according to the size of the window.  I'm currently using MeanMenu (http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/) which is awesome for the menu items, but I don't know how to handle the body.  Super new to HTML/CSS/JQuery - any pointers would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP,

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) may be what you're looking for.

#### Bootstrap handles responsive UI quite nicely.

The **Fluid Grid System** doc has more info and examples, but here's the overview:

> The fluid grid system uses percents instead of pixels for column widths. It has the same responsive capabilities as our fixed grid system, ensuring proper proportions for key screen resolutions and devices.  - via the [Bootstrap Docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

#### UI / Navigation Bar

In addition to responsive design, Bootstrap comes with a bunch of common ui elements/plugins. Like MeanMenu (which admittedly, I lack any knowledge about), Bootstrap does [navigation bars](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar).

#### Plunker, collaborative online editing.

Lastly, since you're just starting out, [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) is a great tool for prototyping, and boilerplates. It's especially helpful for sharing code questions/answers with the SO community.

I put together a [Plunk > http://plnkr.co/edit/LF6BCCDam2w67aUwOSaq](http://plnkr.co/edit/LF6BCCDam2w67aUwOSaq) that includes Bootstrap and an example of a responsive image grid and navigation bars.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: My pleasure, @SB2055—glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Well most modern "responsive" websites use CSS media queries to achieve it, even the website you've linked to, if you look into the CSS you can see this line (among many others):

```
/* This will define the style you want when the screen's Minimum width is 1024px */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
 /* style here */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
 /* style here */
}
```

Those media queries should work in most modern browsers, and for those that don't support it, you can reference [this js](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) that will enable that.

For additional info on media queries, you can try this [tutorial](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/).